# Where can I get latest full updated list of supernovae candidates from the SDSS-II Supernova Survey?

Tags: astronomy, observational-astronomy, data-analysis, supernova, data

I am doing a project where I need the list of supernovae candidates from the Sloan Digital Sky Survey II (SDSS-II) supernova survey.

**[One list](http://www.sdss.org/supernova/snlist_confirmed.html)** is available as part of the data-release-7 (DR7) website. The list contains 902 confirmed candidates.

On the other hand, **[there is a list](http://sdssdp62.fnal.gov/sdsssn/snlist_confirmed_updated.php)** on another website for the supernova-survey project, where the list is supposedly confirmed *and* updated. This list has 1030 candidates.

Not only is is the number of candidates on each list different, but each list has candidates that are not on the other list.

**The question at first, then, was which list is correct one?**

There is no information on the SDSS DR7 website on when the list was last updated, but on the main site for the external project site, the footer says that the page was last modified in 2009, which is after DR7. I am not sure if this date is the same for the page with the actual list, though.

When I inspected the overlapping entries (those sharing the same internal SDSS id), I noticed that the larger list at least for the ones that I looked at, in some places had information in a field that was blank in the smaller list. This was usually the value of the redshift for the given supernova candidate. I took this as an indication that the larger list, i.e. the one that is not on sdss.org, is actually the newer of the two lists.

**But what about the confirmed candidates that are still listed in the older (smaller) list? Are they no longer considered supernovae candidates?**

I do not want to have to guess which list is better one to use, and I am not sure that merging the candidates from the older confirmed list that are not on the newer into the newer list, since there must be a reason why they are not included in the latter in the first place. But this rationale for this decision is not given alongside the list or anywhere else on the project webpage that I looked.

*What I really want is the latest complete and updated list of supernovae candidates available.*

**So the question is, where do I obtain such this list? And when was it made?**